# Wifi and bluetooth not working

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo laptop it shows “no wifi adapter found “ and I cannot connect my blue tooth devices. Any takers ?

Comment: I am having the same issue after the latest update.

Comment: Some users indicated that disabling secure boot in bios settings solved the problem - should worth a try.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 here is my output

https://pastebin.com/R4TdHwfN

I even tried a external USB wifi adapter. Even that didn't work.

Comment: All looks good. The Wi-Fi and BT should be working. I have the same hardware and it works. What does `dmesg | grep iwl` show?